# How to get remaining space with chrome.storage API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am writing a Chrome App using the [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to read and write key-value pairs. Is there a way I can know how much space is remaining? There is a getBytesInUse function, but that doesn't tell me how many free bytes there are.

Comment: Please add the code and the error message that you´re getting.

Comment: See the [documented quotas](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#properties).

Comment: We have overridden the quotas in our app. I was looking for the actual free space available for storage.